# Definition of locally symmetric space of reductive groups

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, reductive-groups, definitions, symmetric-spaces, shimura-varieties

This might seems like a bit of philosophical question and so maybe if I keep reading a bit more, I might get my answer. But, I ask nonetheless.

In my attempt to study Shimura varieties, I came across the definition of a locally symmetric space associated to connected reductive group $G/\mathbb{Q}$ as follows:

> Let $A_G\subset G$ denote the maximal $\mathbb{Q}$-split torus in the center of $G$ and $A_\infty=A_G(\mathbb{R})$. Let $K_{\infty}\subset G(\mathbb{R})$ denote a maximal compact subgroup. If, for any topological group $\mathfrak{G}$, the connected component of the identity is denoted by $\mathfrak{G}^\circ$, then we define $$X=G(\mathbb{R})/A^\circ_\infty K_\infty^\circ.$$ Now, let $\Gamma\subset G(\mathbb{Q})$ be a subgroup such that $\Gamma\cap G(\mathbb{Q})\cap \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ has fintie index in both $\Gamma$ and $G(\mathbb{Q})\cap \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ for some faithful representation $G\hookrightarrow \operatorname{GL}_n$. The locally symmetric space is defined as $$ X(\Gamma)=\Gamma\backslash X. $$

My question is basically, **why?**

Intuitively what is this trying to achieve? As in, why are we quotienting out by $K_\infty^\circ$ and $A_\infty^\circ$ (maybe this is the least we need to do to ensure some kind of compactness-like result, or better cohomology groups)?

I do have some familiarity with moduli spaces of elliptic curves with level structures and I know that we can get examples using this construction (which helps construct Galois representations using certain modular forms), but when I see this construction, it just looks like generalising without any end goal in mind (which is obviously not true and why I said I should probably keep reading rather than ask this question — but I cannot help myself).

I am sure the question sounds vague, but I just don't have an image in mind when I think of these locally symmetric spaces and it would greatly help it someone could help fix that.

Comment: Some Shimura varieties (those of abelian type) classify abelian varieties with additional structure. See:  Deligne, Pierre Travaux de Shimura. (French) Séminaire Bourbaki, 23ème année (1970/1971), Exp. No. 389, pp. 123–165. Lecture Notes in Math., Vol. 244, Springer, Berlin, 1971.

Comment: See also:  Deligne, Pierre Variétés de Shimura: interprétation modulaire, et techniques de construction de modèles canoniques. (French) Automorphic forms, representations and L-functions (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Oregon State Univ., Corvallis, Ore., 1977), Part 2, pp. 247–289, Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., XXXIII, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I., 1979.

Comment: See also papers referring to these two, expecially those by J. S. Milne.

Comment: Are you asking for a (motivating) reason for defining symmetric space, locally symmetric space, or both?

Comment: @MarsaultChabat yes, I am trying to find some motivation so that I can create a better picture in my head. For instance, when someone sees a redictive group, I don't think it is very natural to think that we should try and understand the geoemetry of this quotient. Or is it natural?

Comment: No I'm asking if wether you want information about X or information about Gamma\X or both of them?

Comment: @MarsaultChabat both.

Comment: I'm far from an expert, but  I think it is helpful to start with examples, which have  rich and beautiful geometries.  In the  simplest case: $G=SL_2$, then $X= SL_2(\mathbb{R})/SO_2$ is the upper half plane. Then $X(\Gamma)$ would include modular curves. In the next simplest case, $G$ is the Weil restriction of $SL_2$ of a real quadratic field, and $X(\Gamma)$ would be a Hilbert modular surface....

Comment: This is not the most general definition of a locally symmetric space.

Comment: TeX note: $\Gamma\setminus X$ `\Gamma\setminus X`, as the name suggests, is for set difference.  For the quotient space, you want $\Gamma\backslash X$ `\Gamma\backslash X`.  I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a very natural, intrinsic definition of a "symmetric space", as a manifold (Riemannian or Hermitian) with an extra symmetry of a certain prescribed type. It is then a *theorem*, not a definition, that all such objects have the form $G(\mathbb{R}) / A_\infty^\circ K_\infty^\circ$ for a reductive group $G$. You can find this perspective, for instance, in Milne's "[Shimura Varieties and Moduli](https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/svi.pdf)".

From this perspective, *defining* a symmetric space as $G(\mathbb{R}) / A_\infty^\circ K_\infty^\circ$ is rather misleading. It's common to define it in this way in number-theory texts, because it avoids wading through large amounts of quite intricate (aka: beautiful) differential geometry before getting to the number-theoretic parts of the theory; but it makes the motivation highly non-obvious.

(*Edit*: Just to clarify, this is about *symmetric spaces*, not *locally symmetric spaces*. A locally symmetric space is the quotient of a symmetric space by a discrete subgroup of its automorphism group $G$, so once you understand the motivation for symmetric spaces, the motivation for locally symmetric spaces should hopefully be clear.)

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. Thank you very much.